# I want to generate new vectors from another vector

Tags: vector, clojure

I would like to generate new vectors from a vector of vectors.
I want to select values of the same column to form new vectors.

```
;; eample1
[["3" "4"] ["5" "6"] ["45" "6"]]
;;=> ["3" "5" "45"] 
;;=> ["4" "6" "6"] 

;;example2
[["1"] ["2"] ["3"]]
;;=> ["1" "2" "3"]
```

Comment: just `map` your arguments through a `vector`: `(map vector ["3" "4"] ["5" "6"] ["45" "6"])` => `(["3" "5" "45"] ["4" "6" "6"])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vectors are (partial) functions from index to value, so you can use this along with `mapv`:

```
(mapv #(% index) ["3" "4"] ["5" "6"] ["45" "6"]])
```

Comment: Your solution gave me the idea.

    (mapv vector ["3" "4"] ["5" "6"] ["45" "6"]])

This works, but I still have to find a way of separating the vector to form two different vectors.

    ;;=> ["3" "5" "45"] 
    ;;=> ["4" "6" "6"]

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking how to transpose a vector of vectors, assuming that both of your examples actually output a vector of vectors.

```
(apply mapv vector [["3" "4"] ["5" "6"] ["45" "6"]])
;=> [["3" "5" "45"] ["4" "6" "6"]]

(apply mapv vector [["1"] ["2"] ["3"]])
;=>[["1" "2" "3"]]
```

Here's a way of thinking about the step-by-step evaluation to help understand how it works:

```
(apply mapv vector [["3" "4"] ["5" "6"] ["45" "6"]])

(mapv vector ["3" "4"] ["5" "6"] ["45" "6"])

[(vector "3" "5" "45") (vector "4" "6" "6")]

[["3" "5" "45"] ["4" "6" "6"]]
```